# 2.5 percent increase of previous field?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a series of IDs.  Each ID has dates ranging up to year 2025 from current year.  Each year for each ID has a specific price.

http://i.imgur.com/srplSDo.jpg

Once I get to a certain point with each ID, it no longer has a specific price.  So what I am wanting to do is take the previous years price and increase it by 2.5 percent.  I have figured a way to grab the previous years price with this

```
SELECT a.*, 
       (CASE 
        WHEN a.YEARLY_PRICING is not null 
        THEN a.YEARLY_PRICING 
        ELSE (SELECT b.YEARLY_PRICING 
              FROM #STEP3 b 
              WHERE (a.id = b.id) AND (b.YEAR = a.YEAR-1))*1.025 
        END) AS TEST
FROM #STEP3 a
```

which would provide these results:

http://imgur.com/MJutM99

but the problem I am having is after the first null year, it is still recognizing the previous yearly_pricing as null, which gives me the null results, so obviously this method won't work for me.  Any other suggestions for improvement?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a one time query or something that will be run constantly?  In other words are you just trying to massage the data once?  If once, just use a cursor.

Comment: This query is in a series of queries where the root data is consistently changing through-out the year.  I am not too familiar with cursors so I will look to see if this is a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a way to find not just the previous year (year - 1), but instead the year that is previous and also has a not-null price. To query for such a year (without solving your problem), you would do something like this:

```
select a.*
, (select max(year) 
   from step3 b 
   where a.id=b.id and a.year>b.year and b.yearly_pricing is not null
  ) PRIOR_YEAR
from step3 a
```

Since SQL-Server allows common-table expressions, you can call the above query "TMP", and then approach it this way. The CALC_PRICE in any year will be the price from the "PRIOR_YEAR" found as per the above query, multiplied by factor. That factor will be 1.025 to the POWER of the number of years from "PRIOR_YEAR" to the current year.

You would end up with SQL like this:

```
with TMP AS (
select a.*
, (select max(year) 
   from step3 b 
   where a.id=b.id and a.year>b.year and b.yearly_pricing is not null
  ) PRIOR_YEAR
from step3 a
  )
select t.*, 
  c.yearly_pricing As prior_price, 
  c.yearly_pricing * POWER(1.025 , (t.year-t.prior_year)) calc_price
from tmp t
left join step3 c
on t.id=c.id and t.prior_year = c.year
```

It still has nulls, etc. but those are easily handled with COALESCE() or CASE expressions like you had in your question.

Here's an SQL Fiddle which shows how it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/296a4/21

Comment: You are missing `and t.id = c.id`.

Comment: Thanks. That's what happens when test-data has only one id :)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT ID, Year, Price, Price AS Prev
  FROM T A
  WHERE Year = (SELECT min(year) FROM T WHERE T.ID = A.ID GROUP BY T.ID)
UNION ALL
SELECT T.ID, T.Year, T.Price, ISNULL(T.Price, 1.025*Prev) 
  FROM  T  JOIN CTE ON T.ID = CTE.ID
  AND T.Year - 1 = CTE.YEAR
)

SELECT * FROM CTE
ORDER BY ID, Year
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c45b/6)**